# Partitionning : is it ok to put my OS at the end of my disk?

Tags: partitioning, uefi, htpc, system-reserved-partition

I've build a small HTPC; and I have a 2TB HDD in it.
The idea is to store only medias on that drive, and to have a separate M.2 SSD drive for the OS.

BUT those SSD still are expensive, and i'll wait some time before buying one.  Consequently, I have to put my OS on my HDD momentarily.

Normally, I would partitionate my HDD like this : "boot" (efi) / "OS" / "datas" (which will be almost the entire drive).
But knowing that one day or another, i'll use a SSD card for the OS, I will have to repartitionate my HDD so there is only the "datas" partition on it.

Knowing that it's a pain to move partitions (takes a lot of time), I had that idea to use that partition scheme : "datas" / "boot" / "OS".
So once I'll have the SSD, I'll just have to remove the "boot" and "OS" partitions, extend the "datas" one, and it'll be faster to manage.

My question is : is there a problem with that structure, and does it change something in terms of speed or reliability to put the system partitions at the end of the drive ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: What does your research effort show using Google?

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry my question was downvoted; If I ask here it's because I haven't found anything on Google.  Maybe not the good keywords; and also english is not my mother tongue.  Well; that does not help me so far...

Comment: Edit your question to show you tried researching it but came up with no solutions.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to put an expensive, fast ssd into an htpc to hold the OS when the OS isn't going to be needing hardly any disk IO ( to that drive )?

Comment: I can find no information on this subject, but assume the first or second partition is near the outer edge of the platters an would have faster disk access, read and write times.

Comment: I'm not surprised at the claims that there are some speed differences.  I would expect them to be rather minimal, as psusi's answer indicates.  Reliability would not be expected to be different by any noticeable amount.  Go ahead, place the data towards the end of the drive.  After all, that part of the drive was made for the purpose of storing data.  Software should not have a problem with it.

Comment: While I suspect that you should be fine with the OS at the end of the disk (but I can't say for sure) I *can* say that programs such as Aomei Partition Manager are able to effectively remove and resize partitions towards the front of the disk. I originally had a drive I installed the OS on using the same scheme as you would normally use then migrated the OS to an SSD. I deleted the OS partitions then resized forwards on the drive with Aomei and it claimed it would take 3 hours but took about 15 minutes. Just make sure to close any programs that might be accessing the drive first.

Answer (score 1):

Generally the end of the disk is the slowest part ( but not hugely so ). Given that an htpc isn't going to be accessing the OS drive much, this should not be a problem. If the drive were *over* 2 TB, and you were using bios instead of EFI, that would be a problem as bios can only access 2 TB, but since you are using EFI, you should be good.

Comment: "Generally the end of the disk is the slowest part" Any documents to support this answer? Would be nice. I cannot find any but assume you are correct.

Comment: @Moab, any disk performance benchmark as shown on every disk performance review ever, like those at anandtech, tomshardware, and other review sites.

Comment: Thanks for your answers guys; I think i'll try this then !  Except if someone else has something to say...

Comment: I have seen benchmarks but did not see any showing the difference where the OS is on the platters, Thanks.

Comment: @Moab - there are definately differences - in fact, I'd say the last tracks are about half the speed of the first ones - This is quite noticeable if you use ddrescue to copy a disk - it shows the speed of the reads and how they decrease towards the end of the disk - way moreso then can be explained by buffering, and not apparent on SSD's of-course.  Also, google "Short Stroking" - it uses this effect to speed up disk access at the cost of using less disk space.

Comment: I get it, someone needs to post an answer with these details and supporting links, just saying it makes a difference is not a good answer.